# Cannot make Android Studio use Java 17

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've just upgraded to Gradle 8.0.2, which of course is as much of a nightmare as all the other times I've done this.

However this time I have a problem that I cannot solve :

```
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
> Android Gradle plugin requires Java 17 to run. You are currently using Java 11.
  Your current JDK is located in C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre
```

However, the settings of the project are on Java 17 :

[image]

And the Java version the path indicated in the error is actually 19.
In short, I have no idea where Gradle is getting that Java 11 from (I have no JAVA_HOME variable).